# How to sort all Class properties based on int property in Dart?

Tags: list, class, sorting, dart, flutter

I have Firebase info I'm getting back that includes an int property value.  I've successfully stored them as a class.  Now I would like to make that Class a Map or a List and then sort them descending according to my int Value and create Lists of each property to populate elements later.  Here is my code...

```
class Top {
  String videoId;
  int rank;
  String title;
  String imageString;

  Top({this.videoId, this.rank, this.title, this.imageString});
}

List<Top> videos = new List();
List onesRank = new List();
List onesIds = new List();

for (var items in titles) {

var top = new Top(videoId: items['vidId'], rank: items['Value'],
title: items['vidTitle'], imageString: items['vidImage']);

onesRank.add(top.rank);
onesIds.add(top.videoId);
                      }

print(onesRank);
print(onesIds);
```

Printing `print(top.rank)` successfully logs my int values and `print(onesIds)` logs my ids correctly like so...

`[10, 6, 14, 12, 11, 5, 10, 1]
[4408NthSJis, 7n5ieHnu90w, XuSYtAsMxfY, 9bZkp7q19f0, sGRv8ZBLuW0, 2ips2mM7Zqw, 0Pinupmqwaw, m8MfJg68oCs]`

But I would like to arrange all `top` properties in descending element order as top.rank like so...

`[14, 12, 11, 10, 10, 6, 5, 1]
[XuSYtAsMxfY,9bZkp7q19f0,sGRv8ZBLuW0,4408NthSJis,0Pinupmqwaw,7n5ieHnu90w,
2ips2mM7Zqw,m8MfJg68oCs]`

I accomplished this in Swift like so...

```
for items in snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
                {
                    let ids = items.value["vidId"] as! String
                    let value = items.value["Value"] as! Int
                    let pics = items.value["vidImage"] as! NSString
                    let title = items.value["vidTitle"] as! String

                    let top = Top(videoID: ids, value: value, title: title, imageString: pics as String)
                    videos.append(top)
                }
                videos.sort { $0.value > $1.value }

                self.topTitle = videos.map { $0.title }
                self.topID = videos.map { $0.videoID }
                self.topImage = videos.map { $0.imageString }
                self.vidRank = videos.map { $0.value }
```

Comment: What does "only give back" mean?

Comment: That's all that prints out

Comment: Can you please add example data and what you want the result look like?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I've added an explanation of what I'm trying to accomplish and if you're familiar with Swift, how I made it work there. FYI...  `videos` is instantiated like so...   `var videos = [Top]()`

Comment: @SethLadd "only gives back" means my log prints this out...  `[Instance of 'Top', Instance of 'Top', Instance of 'Top', Instance of 'Top', Instance of 'Top', Instance of 'Top', Instance of 'Top', Instance of 'Top']`

Answer (score 0):

I still don't really understand what you try to accomplish.

If you have a list of `Top` you can do

```
List<Top> videos = new List();
// fill list

videos..sort((a, b) => a.id.compareTo(b.id));
print(videos);
```

Comment: I think this is it. How can I now reverse the sorted List and return to an Instance of Top and use the sorted properties?

Comment: To reverse the order use `(a, b) => b.id.compareTo(a.id));`. I don't kbow what you mean by the rest of the comment.

Comment: 1 more time.  I'm trying to collect elements as properties of my Class "Top"...  then I need to sort those groups of elements in descending order based on the "rank" property...  I then need to use those sorted elements/properties to populate a ListBuilder. The "print" command you provided only logs "Instance of "Top"".  How can I retrieve the sorted elements and correctly populate my ListBuilder properties?  Thank you and sorry for the confusions!

Comment: I still don't understand what "collect elements as properties" could mean. You can override the `toString` method and return a custom string to be used by `print(top)`